# Find for YML and YAML files on bash find

Tags: bash, find, zsh

I am trying to find all `.yaml` and `.yml`

I tried

```
find . -name '*.{yml,yaml}' -exec echo "{}" \;
```

But no results

Neither in the following way

```
find . -name '*.yml' -name '*.yaml' -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Returns nothing.

Is it possible to use the find command to search for both extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `find` find none or one `a`:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*ya?ml$'
```

or

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex '.*ya{0,1}ml$'
```

See: `man find`

Comment: GNU find is awesome

Comment: probably not important unless it's for a script but that regex should find `not.ayaml` - an added `\.` should fix that

Comment: @zapl: I have to agree with you there.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this.

```
find . \( -name '*.yaml' -o -name '*.yml' \)
```

---

- See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)
- See [Understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)