# Bash script not moving files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a bash script that is designed to run in a Linux directory that contains only a collection of image files and video files of varying formats. Once executed, the script looks to see if the Vids and Pics subdirectories exist, and if not, creates them. Then all of the image files are supposed to get moved into Pics and the video files moved into Vids.

But when the script executes the directories get created but none of the files are moved into them.

Any bash experts out there that can take a quick look and suggest a fix?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script will check for the existence of 'Vids' and 'Pics' subdirectories and create them if they do not exist. It will then move all image files into 'Pics' and all video files into 'Vids'. Do you wish to proceed? (y/n)"
read proceed

if [ $proceed == "y" ]; then
  if [ ! -d "Vids" ]; then
    mkdir Vids
  fi
  if [ ! -d "Pics" ]; then
    mkdir Pics
  fi
  find . -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.gif" -exec mv {} Pics/ \;
  find . -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.wmv" -exec mv {} Vids/ \;
  echo "Image files have been moved to 'Pics' and video files have been moved to 'Vids'."
else
  echo "Exiting script."
fi
```

I named the script test.sh and gave it execute permission. When I ran the script, it was run in a directory with a large number of both image and video files. The script asked me if I wanted to continue. When I said yes, it said the directories Vids and Pics was created and all the files moved into them. The script then ends. But none of the files have been moved, although the directories Vids and Pics was created.

Comment: This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101230/find-for-yml-and-yaml-files-on-bash-find/

Comment: No conditions required when doing `mkdir -p Vids` and `mkdir -p Pics`.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit `AND` operator has higher precedence than `-o`, so your command is equivalent to:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.png" -o \( -name "*.gif" -exec mv {} Pics/ \; \)
```

so it only performs `-exec` for `*.gif`, not the other extensions. You need to put parentheses around all the `-name` expressions.

```
find . \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.png" -o -name "*.gif" \) -exec mv {} Pics/ \;
```